# output response in swagger

Tags: c#, swagger, mediatr

I have request and response classes like this:

```
public class CreateResponse : IResponse
{
    public long UniqueNumber {get; set;}

    public long RecordVersion {get; set;}
}

public class CreateRequest:IRequest<CreateResponse>
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Code {get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public interface IResponse
{
    long UniqueNumber {get; set;}
}
```

now. in my controller, set action like this:

```
public async Task<ICreateResponse> MyAction(CreateRequest request)
{
    ICreateResponse response = await _mediator.Send(request);
    return response;
}
```

i use MediatR Package and expect this output

```
{
    "uniqueNumber" : 1254684
}
```

but it return this:

```
{
    "uniqueNumber" : 1254684,
    "recordVersion" : 24887
}
```

How do I get this output?

```
{
    "uniqueNumber" : 1254684
}
```

Comment: you are returning ICreateResponse  not IResponse

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning CreateResponse in your Handler. If you don't need to RecordVersion property so remove it from CreateResponse or create another child class for IResponse without RecordVersion also you can return the type in your handler with type of IResponse.